# No result on Query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Please Help!
I have 3 tables:

```
 employee, 
 assign, 
 vehicle.
```

Only 2 employees can occupy 1 car. I need to select all employees that are not housing any vehicle.

Query:

```
select EID,
    Employee_name
from employee
where EID not in (
        select user1
        from assign
        )
    and EID not in (
        select user2
        from assign
        )
```

this query works if all the cells in "user1" or "user2" are filled.
If the assign table has a null value for "user1" or "user2"

Assign Table values

[image]

the query output is empty

Query result

[image]

If fill it in with a value, it will return all EID(s) and employee_name(s)
that are not in User1 and User2 in the assigned table. AKA it works normally if all user1 and user2 are filled. How do I remake this query in such a way that it will display all available employees regardless if the assign.user1 or assign.user2 is empty.

Comment: Still struggling. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select eid,
    employee_name
from employee e
where not exists (
        select 1
        from assign a
        where e.eid in (a.user1, a.user2)
        );
```

Comment: Is this SQL? I'm using MySQL and this syntax is different from what ive learned

Comment: Yes it is should work just fine on MySQL. Please give it a try.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I didn't know you can rename this way.

Answer (score 1):

Both answers work fine. If you want to learn more on why your query does not work, here is a short explanation.

The problem comes from how SQL treats `NULL` values. SQL is not based on a two valued logic, but on a three valued logic: namely, `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `UNKNOWN`.
In your query, whenever `EID` is compared with a `NULL` value in either the `user1` or `user2` column, the result is neither `TRUE` nor `FALSE`, but `UNKNOWN`.

Another way out of these is to use the functions `COALESCE()` or `IFNULL()`:

[w3schools on coalesce(), ifnull() and others](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)

For more info on all these, you can check the oracle documentation, among other sources:

[oracle documentation on nulls](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements005.htm#SQLRF51083)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, That makes so much sense

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT NULL` as well

```
SELECT eid, employee_name
FROM employee
WHERE eid not in (
  SELECT user1
  FROM assign
  WHERE user1 IS NOT NULL
  UNION
  SELECT user2
  FROM assign
  WHERE user2 IS NOT NULL
)
```